# Dependent Conditional Probability Loop

Tags: statistics

I'm learning some basic statistics right now and I'm having difficulty wrapping my head around how to go about calculating conditional probability for dependent events.

My textbook says that
$$\ P( A | B) = \frac{P(A∩B)}{P(B)}$$

but I have no clue how to get P(A∩B) for dependent events. Looking online, it just says that it equals

$$\ P(A∩B) = {P(A|B)} * {P(B)}$$

which is just the same equation as the one in the textbook, just rearranged a bit.

If I try to solve for one, then I need a value from the other, and to solve for the other, I need a value from the previous. It seems like this would just loop forever to me.

I'm not really sure what to do. Any explanation would be really appreciated, especially if it's easy to understand.

Comment: This is too vague. The answer depends on the joint distribution of A,B. That is,  you need more information

Comment: Typically, in a probability problem where you need to compute $~p(A|B),~$ the problem will provide you with an alternate means of computing both $~p(A \cap B),~$ and $~p(B).$

Comment: Re last comment, assume that you roll a fair 6-sided die.  Let $~A~$ denote the event that you roll $~\leq 3,~$ and let $~B~$ denote the event that you roll an even number.  You can routinely determine both $~p(A \cap B) = \dfrac{1}{6}~$ and $~p(B) = \dfrac{3}{6}.~$  Therefore, you can compute $~p(A|B) = \dfrac{1}{3}.$